# power cable connection inside ATS

Tags: generator

it is known that ATS is used to switch power between generator and utility. but what will happen if we interchange the connection of power cable in the wrong way.(on ATS contact for utility and generator end is present, so what will happen if we wrongly connect those power cables.)

Comment: Can you provide a link for ATS?

Comment: Automatic Transfer Switch?

Comment: yes an automatic transfer switch.

Answer (score 3):

The transfer switch selects "generator" whenever "utility" is not present. If you swap the inputs, it will select "utility" whenever "generator" is not present. In other words, it will not respond automatically to utility outages.

In fact, assuming the switch is also responsible for starting the generator, the switch will keep cycling: It will start the generator and switch to utility power; but once the generator gets going, it will switch back to the generator input and then shut down the generator again. This will repeat over and over, which will be hard on the generator, not to mention all of the attached loads.